# ld cannot find -lmkl_rt although the lib exists

Tags: linux, linker, fortran, ld

## Sorry for the frequently-asked question.

## I'm compiling with make, then I got the error:

```
ld: cannot find -lmkl_rt
make: *** [fesom_ini] Error 1
```

## then I use the ld command in verbose mode:

```
ld -L/opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64 -lmkl_rt --verbose
```

## and everything seems OK:

```
attempt to open /opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_rt.so succeeded
-lmkl_rt (/opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_rt.so)
libdl.so.2 needed by /opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_rt.so
found libdl.so.2 at /lib64/libdl.so.2
libc.so.6 needed by /lib64/libdl.so.2
found libc.so.6 at /lib64/libc.so.6
ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 needed by /lib64/libdl.so.2
found ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 at /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; not setting start address
```

## and I'm pretty sure that this libmkl_rt.so exists:

```
blogin3:/gfs2/work/FESOM1.4/src $ ll /opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_rt.so 
-rwxrwxr-x 1 bzfbtuma aws 5987677 12. Okt 11:12 /opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_rt.so
```

## ALSO, in Makefile.in,

```
LIB_LAP = -L/opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64 -lmkl_rt
exe: $(objs)
ftn -o exe $(LIB_LAP)
```

## Could somebody help me about this?

## Any suggestions will be appreciated.

## Thanks.

Comment: What is in objsm looks like you don't have a main program.

Comment: hi albert. Actually there is a main.f90: ftn -o exe main.f90 $(LIB_LAP)